# Can I update an existing Amazon S3 object?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I was looking at Amazon S3 Samples, and the samples are there for inserts/deletes...

But I want to update an existing blob with fresh data. Basically the content is a text file, and the text has been modified, I want the S3 object to store the new text content.

How do I do this in Java?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Updating an existing object in [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) doesn't differ from creating it in the first place, i.e. the very same [PUT Object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) operation is used to upload the object and will overwrite the existing one (if it isn't protected by other means, e.g. via [Using Bucket Policies](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucketPolicies.html) or [Object Versioning](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html))

You can find a complete code sample in [Upload an Object Using the AWS SDK for Java](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html), the main part boils down to:

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials(
        S3Sample.class.getResourceAsStream(
                "AwsCredentials.properties")));
try {
    System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
    File file = new File(uploadFileName);
    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
                             bucketName, keyName, file));

 } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
    System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which " +
            "means your request made it " +
            "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response" +
            " for some reason.");
    // ... error handling based on exception details
}
```

Comment: What Steffen is also saying is that there is no 'partial blob' updating. You need to upload the entire new copy of the file.

Comment: @Steffen - I am new to S3, hence a quick related question - if I have a huge csv file of 1 GB for e.g. in an S3 bucket and I want to add a new row to it. What is the optimal way of doing this operation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Athena to update with extra rows via an INSERT function. You will need to provide Athena with access to the S3 bucket, crawl the S3 bucket using Amazon Glue to get the table layout, update Glue for the Schema names and data types. Once this has been done you can then update using the Athena console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/athena/home

```
INSERT INTO destination_table [(col1,col2,...)]
VALUES (col1value,col2value,...)[,(col1value,col2value,...)][,...]
```

Comment: I would assume this still performs a PUT operation under the hood.

Comment: I believe this happens on the server, so while still a put operation the user does not need to download, transform and load the data. My experience is considerable time saving.