# Can I update an existing Amazon S3 object header properties?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a problem of Content-Type empty for video files and wanted to update those objects with Content-Type: video/** based on extension of the file. But when i am using the put method for same key/bucket with content-type it is being overridden with '0' content-length.

[Can I update an existing Amazon S3 object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517198/can-i-update-an-existing-amazon-s3-object) link says
put will override the file s3 object which doesn't serve my purpose.

Note: I don't want to use Java SDK. I want to use normal the Java httpput due to memory constraints of the mobile.

Comment: This is a bit strange in the s3 REST api. PUT should be used to create items, POST to update, but they are using both, PUT and POST to create objects. To be honest I don't see a possibility to update, though I know it can be done since both the web-client as well as client tools are able to update properties.

Answer (score 5):

What you could try is to use the [PUT COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) request with the same source and target.

```
PUT /yourvideo.flv HTTP/1.1
Host: bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2009 22:32:00 GMT
x-amz-copy-source: /bucket/yourvideo.flv
Authorization: AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:0RQf4/cRonhpaBX5sCYVf1bNRuU=
```

Apparently [python boto](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/s3/key.py) modifies metadata this way

Yes, I can confirm, copy is working:

```
PUT /test/123.png HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com\r\n
Accept-Encoding: identity\r\n
Content-Length: 0\r\n
x-amz-storage-class: STANDARD\r\n
x-amz-copy-source: yourbucket/test/123.png\r\n
Date: Fri, 11 Jan 2013 15:16:48 GMT\r\n
Content-Type: image/gif\r\n # this is the content-type set
Authorization: AWS AKXXXXXDDRXXXXXX63CA:RcktkZ9nPwsXXXXXd+KXXXXXY=\r\n
x-amz-metadata-directive: REPLACE\r\n
\r\n
```

**S3 Reply:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: Vf1bRJd+e4ru0y73GB0Ra0xYB2vv6GLWYKsHAC4AzE+a8uZB56Xy8+YTDkJ0/wfN
x-amz-request-id: C0E6A2823F3FB3E9
Date: Fri, 11 Jan 2013 15:16:49 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 234
Server: AmazonS3
```

**Verification:**

```
HEAD /test/123.png HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com\r\n
Accept-Encoding: identity\r\n
Date: Fri, 11 Jan 2013 15:25:23 GMT\r\n
Content-Length: 0\r\n
Authorization: AWS AXXXIXXXXMDDXXXXX7XXXCA :HoZ4Woxxw6SWlxxxx000Rxxm8ODQ=\r\n
\r\n
```

S3 replies with the correct content-type ( the one I set wrongly to image/gif instead of image/png )

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: 7Ut6sdm6i+1h7Di5UrB4v9Sn3mVCNjyDnkb4rm1jGzN6wBTgDT2/yCSHdrKG12Jd
x-amz-request-id: 38A1F6EC6ECD1D2D
Date: Fri, 11 Jan 2013 15:25:24 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 11 Jan 2013 15:25:24 GMT
ETag: "c09fad0faf4e6bb1148670af78b6de41"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Length: 122311
Server: AmazonS3
```