# How to overwrite the output directory in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I'm reading a json file and I wish to modify some changes in the json file. After modification I would like to overwrite in the same json file. When I'm doing that, MapReduce throws an exception as "FileAlreadyExists". Please give me a solution to overwrite in the same file. I'm not interested to delete the file and create a new file. I just wants to overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

HDFS does not allow writes in the existing files. You have to delete the files first and re-write them. The in-place update to file is not supported in HDFS. The HDFS was design to provide high read on the existing data. So the feature you are expecting is not available in HDFS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Abhishek.  As per my project requirement, I have to read a json file in S3Bucket(it has nearly 5000 json files) and I wish to overwrite in the same file. Is there any way to achieve this task?

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517198/can-i-update-an-existing-amazon-s3-object). Might help you. I am not aware of Amazon S3. I have given my answer in Hadoop (MapReduce and HDFS) context.

Comment: I would suggest you to explain your question properly as what exactly are you looking for and what is the environment you are using.

Comment: I have nearly 5000 json files in the S3bucket. Using MapReduce, I'm accessing and reading the json files in the S3bucket. I have done some modification in the read json file in the Mapper Class. In the reducer class, I would like to upload the modified json files in the S3 bucket. Since, the files are already there so mapreduce doesn't allow me to overwrite it throws an exception as "File already exists".

Comment: I already used that approach, the link which you given to me. In that approach, I can able to read and overwrite in the S3bucket successfully. It works fine only in eclipse. When I export that into jar and run in terminal, I am not able overwrite in the file, and also it doesn't shows any error as "Filealreadyexist".

Comment: I have to run the job in EMR(AWS). In that case, I'm using maven, to built jar. Using that jar, I run the job in EMR. The link which you given to me works in the IDE, but not once converted to jar. I'm using Hadoop 2.4.0